# Link does not use default CSS

Tags: html, css, angular, hyperlink

I have a link ("Go back") towards the bottom of this html.

```
<div style="margin-top: 5em; display: flex; justify-content: center; height: 100vh; align-items: center;">

    <div class="shadow-lg p-0 mb-5 bg-white rounded" style="padding: 3em;">
        
        <div class="card-body">
            <h6 style="margin-top: 0.3em; font-size: medium;">Reset password</h6>
            <form [formGroup]="passwordResetForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="email">Email address</label>
                    <input type="text" formControlName="email" class="form-control"
                        [ngClass]="{ 'is-invalid': submitted && f.username.errors }" />
                    <div *ngIf="submitted && f.email.errors" class="invalid-feedback">
                        <div *ngIf="f.email.errors.required">Email address is required</div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="d-flex justify-content-between" style="padding-top: 1em;">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <button [disabled]="loading" class="btn btn-primary">
                            <span *ngIf="loading" class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm mr-1"></span>
                            Reset password
                        </button>
                    </div>
                    <a class="p-2" routerLink="../login">Go back</a>
                </div>

               
                <div *ngIf="error" class="alert alert-danger mt-3 mb-0">{{error}}</div>
            </form>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**The link WORKS**. But I simply cannot get it to look like a link. i.e. no underline, no hand cursor.

There is absolutely no CSS anywhere in my project for links. I only use out-of-the-box standard links (black text, black underline, hand icon on hover).

I tried adding some CSS to this link (a:hover) but it ignored me.

I have other html files in this dir with the same links that look as expected. Only this one file refuses.

I have absolutely no logic in my component.ts. Only the class declaration and decorator things.

[image: what it looks like]

[image: what other files look like]

Comment: How does the rendered a tag looks like (dev tools > elements), is there a `href="..."` attribute? If no, did you import RouterModule to the module where your component is declared?

Comment: Open dev tools, select your element, click 'Computed' and you can see the CSS being used to calculate each attribute of an element.

Comment: @ChristophLütjen not sure if I looked in the right place but
it says this: 
a:not([href]) {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
}

Comment: I have RouterModule

Comment: When you inspect an element, you see your DOM (the HTML) on the left side and node properties (e.g. your CSS) on the right side. Now look at the left side and you'll see that your link has no `href` attribute. Because it has no href, it will a) not work and b) not look like a link. Typical reasons: RouterModule not loaded (in the module where your component is declared!!) or wrong route in `routerLink` attribute. As soon as you see the href attribute your link will work and look like a link (no need for any additional styles or !important here).

Comment: But the link works. That was never the issue. It always worked. It just never *looked* like a link

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By seeing the code you posted I think the route is mentioned incorrect it wont have dots preceding the route as base DIR is already set something like below...

```html
<!--Incorrect -->
<a class="p-2" routerLink="../login">Go back</a>

<!--Correct -->
<a class="p-2" routerLink="/login">Go back</a>
```

Coming to the CSS try adding important to the style you are trying to add as below.

```css
a:hover {
 text-decoration: underline !important;
  color: #3B5998 !important;
}
a{
  cursor: pointer !important;
}
```

And also check the RouterModule import in the app.module.ts file.
Ref [Link](https://angular.io/api/router/RouterModule)

Comment: You need the RouterModule in the module, where the component is declared - that may or may not be the app module - to make the directive work

Comment: It works. the link *behaves* correctly it just doesn't *look* correct.